# How to Implement in Annotate and Filter in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset, django-annotate

This is a follow up to a previous question but I will include all the detail here.

I'm creating a game where one of the elements is that players vote for each other.

Here are the models I've set up (relevant fields only)

My `models.py`

```
class Game(models.Model):
  gamecode = ShortUUIDField(length=4, max_length=4, unique=True)
  phasenumber = models.IntegerField(default=1)
  isActive = models.BooleanField(default=True)

class Player(models.Model):
  game = models.ForeignKey(Game, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  isPlaying = models.BooleanField(default=True)

class PlayerVote(models.Model):
  byplayer = models.ForeignKey(Player, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  forplayer = models.ForeignKey(Player, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="voteforplayer")
  gamephasenumber = models.IntegerField()
  timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

When a user joins a game, they get an entry in the "Player" model.  When they cast a vote for another player, an entry is added to the "PlayerVote" model showing which player voted (byplayer), who they voted for (forplayer), and the phase that the game is in (gamephasenumber) (this is just an integer that increases each phase of the game)

What I'd like to do is create a QuerySet which contains each player and how many votes they got in this phase of the game.

I can do the below to get the votes they've received for all phases

```
playerswithvotes = Player.objects.select_related('game').filter(game = activegame.game, game__phasenumber = activegame.game.phasenumber, isPlaying = True).annotate(votesreceived=Count('voteforplayer')).order_by('-votesreceived')
```

But how can I show just the votes they've received in this phase number?

I have tried each of the below:

```
votesthisround = Count("playervote", filter=Q(playervote__gamephasenumber = activegame.game.phasenumber))
playerswithvotes = Player.objects.select_related('game').filter(game = activegame.game, game__phasenumber = activegame.game.phasenumber, isPlaying = True).annotate(votesreceived=votesthisround).order_by('-votesreceived')
```

```
playerswithvotes = Player.objects.select_related('game').filter(game = activegame.game, game__phasenumber = activegame.game.phasenumber, isPlaying = True).annotate(votesreceived=Count('voteforplayer', filter=Q(playervote__gamephasenumber = activegame.game.phasenumber))).order_by('-votesreceived')
```

```
playerswithvotes = Player.objects.select_related('game').filter(game = activegame.game, game__phasenumber = activegame.game.phasenumber, isPlaying = True).annotate(votesreceived=Count('voteforplayer')).filter(playervote__gamephasenumber = activegame.game.phasenumber).order_by('-votesreceived')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query:

```py
PlayerVote.objects.filter(forplayer__game=activegame.game, gamephasenumber=activegame.game.phasenumber).values("forplayer").annotate(votes=Count("pk"))
```

The use of `.values()` lets us use `GROUP BY` in the SQL query that Django generates, so we can have the output grouped by the recipient of the PlayerVotes. The result look like: `<QuerySet [{'forplayer': 1, 'votes': 1}, {'forplayer': 3, 'votes': 2}]>`

If you wanted a summary of which players received votes in each round, you can remove the game phase from the filter and add it to the `.values()` part of the query:

```py
PlayerVote.objects.filter(forplayer__game=activegame.game).values("forplayer", "gamephasenumber").annotate(votes=Count("pk"))
```

The output looks like: `<QuerySet [{'forplayer': 1, 'gamephasenumber': 1, 'votes': 1}, {'forplayer': 2, 'gamephasenumber': 2, 'votes': 2}, {'forplayer': 3, 'gamephasenumber': 1, 'votes': 2}, {'forplayer': 3, 'gamephasenumber': 2, 'votes': 1}]>`

Comment: This looks like just what I need... However, when I've tried it, the QuerySet doesn't seem to have done the GROUP BY when I use `logger.info(playerswithvotes.values())` to see the results. Instead, I get `<QuerySet [{'id': 378, 'byplayer_id': 43, 'forplayer_id': 45, 'gamephasenumber': 5, 'timestamp': datetime.datetime(2024, 3, 18, 11, 24, 43, 571827, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc), 'votesreceived': 1}, {...}, {...} ]>`.  To check what was going on, I looked at the SQL and it does just have the 2x fields in the SELECT part which seems very strange

Comment: If you've saved the query that I suggested as `playerswithvotes`, then just log that variable. Don't log `playerswithvotes.values()`, which will just return dictionary representations of each object in the queryset. Calling `.values()` a second time is changing the result